Is it strange if I start learning frontend?
I've always loved doing research, and I’m now a PhD student in computer science, focusing on AI at a good university. But recently, I’ve been feeling terrible. My performance has been poor, and it’s frustrating because I’m putting in long hours at the university — often more than anyone else I know. Yet, I’m still not productive.
I'm 29, which sometimes feels too old to start learning something new. I want to continue my PhD mainly to stay in my current country; I don’t want to return to my home country. But I'm not sure if I'll be able to stay or if they’ll ask me to leave because of my performance.
On top of this, I’ve never worked in the industry. I've always been drawn to frontend development and wanted to try it, but I’ve never had the chance. Do you think it's possible to start learning frontend in my spare time and switch to that after finishing my PhD? By then, I’ll be around 32, starting out as a junior, which is hard to accept. I’ve built a strong academic record, yet I feel ready to leave it all behind.

Note that your performance is likely poor because you are putting in long hours at the university, not despite it. Humans need to rest and relax regularly.

I don't know. Thank you for your comment.

May I point out the story of Prof. Sue Black (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sue_Black_(computer_scientist))? Prof. Black started a PhD at age 31 (after a rather difficult early life) and went on to have more success and impact than most academics can ever hope for. So I seriously doubt that 29 is too old to learn frontend development, a concept that you can pick up the basics in in a matter of weeks or months.

What does "frontend" refer to?

@WolfgangBangerth User-facing parts of software, commonly web UI. As opposed to "backend" which handles the actual storage, processing and similar tasks.


I'm 29, which sometimes feels too old to start learning something new.

Bull. You think being 29 makes you too old? I know people in their 60s who have been successful in PhD programs. Moreover, I think you know this is bull, since your "Plan B" also involves learning something completely new (front-end development). If you want to quit your PhD, fine, but be honest with yourself about the reasons.

I want to continue my PhD mainly to stay in my current country; I don’t want to return to my home country.

You are presumably on a student visa, so your presence is inherently temporary. Unless you have a plan to obtain permanent residency, this merely postpones the inevitable.

Do you think it's possible to start learning frontend in my spare time....

Is it possible? Well, yes, of course. But I don't think it's a good idea. If you wanted to take up sumo wrestling in your spare time, fine, that sounds like a good hobby. But learning front-end will use many of the same muscles that you should be using to be successful in your PhD. This is not a good hobby, this is adding even more work onto your plate, at a time when you are already struggling.
So again, I think you need to be honest with yourself about your plans here. If you are serious about finishing your PhD, then you should avoid distractions like this. Whereas if you've decided to quit your PhD, then fine. But have the courage to make an affirmative decision, rather than just putting less and less effort into your PhD until they eventually fire you.

By then, I’ll be around 32, starting out as a junior, which is hard to accept. I’ve built a strong academic record, yet I feel ready to leave it all behind.

So the good news is that if you make an affirmative decision to switch, then you don't need to wait until you're 32. If this is the right choice, then you can save two years and add at least $100K to your lifetime earnings. You'll be happier and richer!
On the other hand, it sounds like you've never done front end development before. Switching career paths to something totally new seems a little bit reckless. Further, the job market for front-end development is relatively saturated, and AI is changing things rapidly. I cannot, of course, tell you which career to pick, but be cautious of thinking that "the grass is greener on the other side" -- instead, think carefully about the pros and cons of all your options. Good luck.

Yes, especially as you said, "The grass is greener on the other side." This is a huge fear for me. I know the current situation was my dream in the past, and now I am in trouble. What will happen again if I switch? I don't know.
To be honest, the learning at my age was about all things, including the front.
Thank you at all.
Yes, that's right; I have to think more and be honest with myself (I don't know how :)) ). Thank you

"If you choose not to decide, you still have made a choice" as is well known to Rush fans.
